# Send update on twitter in ASP.NET Webforms throw proxy

Tags: asp.net, webforms

in my country twitter is filter and we should access it by proxy and VPN,
now i want to send update to twitter in ASP.NET Webforms and my code works fine when VPN is connected but if i disconnect VPN it does not work.
Is there any way to use vpn account in project?
This is my project for sending update to twitter :

```
var auth = new AspNetAuthorizer
            {
                CredentialStore = new SessionStateCredentialStore
                {
                    ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"],
                    ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"],
                    OAuthToken = "MyToken",
                    OAuthTokenSecret = "SecretToken",
                    UserID = MyUserId,
                    ScreenName = "UserName"
                }
            };

            var ctx = new TwitterContext(auth);

            await ctx.TweetAsync(UpdateTextBox.Text);

            SuccessLabel.Visible = true;
```

in this code when i connect to VPN it works fine and sends update but when i disable VPN it shows error :

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it 10.10.34.36:443

another error :

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.10.34.36:443

is there any way to fix this problem? In my country we can not access to twitter website and should use VPN.

Comment: You need to supply a lot more information about the problem, include your code so people can see exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok i will in 2-3 hours later

Comment: @RMadd i added my code and error, can you help me?

Comment: The code you provided does not help to solve the issue. You need to provide the code you are using to connect to VPN.

Comment: I dont know how to connect to vpn in ASP.NET WebForms, i have a vpn connection on my computer with username and password and server then i connect by it, my connection in like a Dial Up connection